# How to access katakana on the Japanese keyboard for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, language, japanese

I have the Japanese keyboard enabled and am able to input hiragana and kanji fine, but I can find no way to input katakana. How can this be done?

Comment: Romaji keyboard or Kana?  Don’t you see them in the candidate field above the keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

After keying the hiragana, You should always find the katakana somewhere in the suggestion bar above the keyboard.

[image]